# Как создать эффект (анимацию) вращения по оси Y объекта формы монеты с помощью СSS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация, css-animation

Была задумка сделать вращение круга, который по оси Z растягивался б на 20+ px (чтобы видно было толщину, как у ребра монеты), но как только я начал выставлять элементы по оси Z, элементы стали вращаться по совсем другой траектории. Как можно получить вышеописанный эффект с помощью CSS/JS/SVG?

[image: вращение монеты]

Второй вопрос: сейчас я использую `setTimeout` из-за того, что мои классы немедленно присваиваются и я вижу поворот по оси Y только 1 раз из 8 загрузок страницы. Как инициализировать поворот через класс без функции `setTimeout`, чтобы это срабатывало с каждой загрузкой страницы?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   //document.querySelector(".side").classList.add('active');
  function flipCircle(n){
   setTimeout( ()=> {n.classList.add('active')}, 50);
  }
   var sides = document.getElementsByClassName("side");
    for (var i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {   
      flipCircle(sides[i]);
    }
});
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Digital Numbers';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Digital Numbers'), url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/15953/DigitalNumbers-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #0a0a0a;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
h1 {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 260px;
  line-height: 290px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: glow 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  font-family: 'Digital Numbers', sans-serif;
}
.flip {
  margin: calc(50vh - 250px) auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  animation: border-glow 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  border: 100px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: transform 30s cubic-bezier(1,.01,1,.5), border 500ms ease-in-out;;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.shuf-front {
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/FgBcMfm/shuf-771.png'); 
}

.shuf-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(-1, 1);
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/FgBcMfm/shuf-771.png');
}

.active {
  transform: rotateY(calc(-2000 * 360deg));
}

/*rotateX(calc(2000 * 360deg))  */

@keyframes glow {
  0%,100%{ text-shadow:0 0 30px red; }
  25%{ text-shadow:0 0 50px orange; }
  50%{ text-shadow:0 0 50px forestgreen; }
  75%{ text-shadow:0 0 50px cyan; }
}

@keyframes border-glow {
  0%,100%{ border: 10px solid red; }
  25%{ border: 20px solid orange; }
  50%{ border: 10px solid forestgreen; }
  75%{ border: 20px solid blue; }
}

@keyframes wobble {
  0%,100%{ transform:rotate3d(1,1,0,40deg); }
  25%{ transform:rotate3d(-1,1,0,40deg); }
  50%{ transform:rotate3d(-1,-1,0,40deg); }
  75%{ transform:rotate3d(1,-1,0,40deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1><h1>3</h1>
    
  </div>

<div class="flip">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="shuf-front side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-back side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-front side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-back side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-front side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-back side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-front side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-back side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-front side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-back side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-front side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-back side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-front side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-back side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-front side"></div>
     <div class="shuf-back side"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хороший, интересный вопрос

Comment: @Alexandr_TT практикуюсь в CSS )))

Comment: хорошо бы добавить ещё 2-3 скриншота, как на самом деле тебе хочется видеть промежуточный и финальный результаты анимации. Ведь слова понимаются по разному..

Comment: @Alexandr_TT сейчас исправим

Comment: https://codepen.io/xforhu/pen/zYzKypY

Comment: @highpassion Замечательные, полезные ответы, пробежался по всем с (+) Вот так, хороший вопрос сгенерировал отличные ответы!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT точно так же прошелся по ответам, реально круто у ребят вышло, надеюсь, что поможет другим ищущим, а то самые популярные вопросы про форму сферы ) благодарю Вас за советы по оформлению, а вот кому поставить верный ответ даже не знаю, думаю, завтра по апвоутам выбрать победителя )

Comment: @highpassion При наличии нескольких сильных ответов, конфликт интересов неизбежен. Каждый считает свой ответ наилучшим. Но галочка то одна... Поэтому лучше выступать в роли `самодура` - Этот ответ я понимаю, он мне подходит лучше других и точка. Такое решение люди поймут. Но, на мой взгляд, сделав выбор, не стоит менять его,- перебрасывать галочку. Вот это намного обидней, чем первичный выбор. Если вам хочется как-то ещё дополнительно поблагодарить, тех кому не досталась галочка, то можно плюсануть другие сильные ответы из профиля

Comment: @Alexandr_TT согласен полностью, хорошие советы!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Монетка с ребром

```css
.coin {
  --diameter:200px;
  --thickness:20px;
  --scale:0.75;
  --period:5s;
  --gradient: linear-gradient(gold 0%, yellow 50%, gold 100%);
  
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: var(--diameter);
  height: var(--diameter);
  animation: spin var(--period) linear infinite;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gold; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: calc(var(--diameter) * 0.6);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.head {
  transform: translateZ(calc(var(--thickness) / 2)); 
  animation: flip-head var(--period) linear infinite;
}

.tail {
  transform:
    translateZ(calc(0px - var(--thickness) / 2)) 
    rotateY(180deg);
  animation: flip-tail var(--period) linear infinite;
}

.edge {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--thickness);
  height: 100%;
  transform:
    translateX(calc(var(--diameter) / 2))
    translateZ(calc(var(--thickness) / 2))
    rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background-color: gold;
  background-image: var(--gradient);
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(var(--scale));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(var(--scale));
  }
}

@keyframes flip-tail {
  0% {
    background-image: var(--gradient);
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background-image: none;
    color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: var(--gradient);
    color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes flip-head {
  0% {
    background-image: none;
    color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-image: var(--gradient);
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: none;
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="coin">
  <div class="side head">$</div>
  <div class="side tail">1</div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
</div>
```

В основе решения идея, реализованная в первом ответе от Andrey Fedorov — плавная анимация вращения вокруг оси Y, и пошаговая смена фона.

Однако, если смотреть на объект строго в направлении оси Z, то можно добиться иллюзии объема за счет синхронного вращения двух скругленных плоскостей и вертикального прямоугольника ("ребра"), проходящего через центры кругов под углом 90 градусов. Ширина прямоугольника должна быть равна расстоянию между кругами по оси Z.

При вращении дальний от наблюдателя круг принимает цвет ребра и незаметно сливается с ним в положениях, близких к 90 и 270 градусам. Одинаковая градиентная заливка ребра и дальнего круга усиливает эффект, создавая иллюзию кривизны поверхности.

[image: схема анимации]

Ниже схематическая анимация с полупрозрачными элементами:

```css
.coin {
  --diameter:200px;
  --thickness:20px;
  --scale:0.75;
  --period:5s;
  --gradient: linear-gradient(blue 0%, blue 100%);
  
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: var(--diameter);
  height: var(--diameter);
  animation: spin var(--period) linear infinite;
}

.side {
  opacity:0.75;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: calc(var(--diameter) * 0.6);
}

.head {
  transform: translateZ(calc(var(--thickness) / 2)); 
  animation: flip-head var(--period) linear infinite;
}

.tail {
  transform:
    translateZ(calc(0px - var(--thickness) / 2)) 
    rotateY(180deg);
  animation: flip-tail var(--period) linear infinite;
}

.edge {
  opacity:0.75;
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--thickness);
  height: 100%;
  transform:
    translateX(calc(var(--diameter) / 2))
    translateZ(calc(var(--thickness) / 2))
    rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background-color: gold;
  background-image: var(--gradient);
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(var(--scale));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(var(--scale));
  }
}

@keyframes flip-tail {
  0% {
    background-image: var(--gradient);
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background-image: none;
    color: green;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: var(--gradient);
    color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes flip-head {
  0% {
    background-image: none;
    color: green;
  }
  50% {
    background-image: var(--gradient);
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-image: none;
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="coin">
  <div class="side head">$</div>
  <div class="side tail">1</div>
  <div class="edge"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: очень крутой результат! самый минималистичный по объему кода, думаю, вы ближе всех подошли к оптимальному решению )

Comment: @highpassion Ведьмаку заплатите чеканной монетой ✅

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Отличная реализация! Спасибо. В принципе решение более-менее понятно. Контейнер с тремя объектами вращается. Внутри каждого объекта свои трансформации, анимации. Но у вас наверняка были вопросы, идеи, как это всё связать в целостную картинку. Не могли бы вы поделиться в комментариях к коду, основными идеями, тонкостями решения.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT +1

Comment: Добавил пояснительную записку @Alexandr_TT

Comment: @Alexey Vladimirov благодарю. Всё внимательно прочитал, понял идею. Особая благодарность за поясняющий пример. Оч. приятно встретить человека, который умеет кратко и доходчиво объяснять. Эта такая редкость в настоящее время.

Answer (score 5):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #D1C7BB;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://i115.fastpic.org/thumb/2021/0905/38/_94172dc7f7cefcb43a44012c6c104438.jpeg);
  animation: bshit 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes bshit {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
    background-image: url(https://i115.fastpic.org/thumb/2021/0905/38/_94172dc7f7cefcb43a44012c6c104438.jpeg);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url(https://i115.fastpic.org/thumb/2021/0905/35/_41069afe25725a9574235b4b84009235.jpeg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: окей, это не трехмерный круг, но бесконечная анимация может дать стопроцентное срабатывание, ставлю Вам плюс

Comment: А можно ли как-то назначить разные фоны для аверса/реверса? Орел и решку можно сделать?

Comment: @Leonid можно, это мало что мне дает. первоначальный вариант моего shuffie-flipper'a так и выглядел

Comment: @Leonid как я понимаю, для обеих сторон анимация начнется одновременно

Comment: А что не устраивает? Толщины нет? Что значит "не трехмерный круг"? И почему мало что дает такой вариант?

Comment: добавил разные стороны...

Comment: @Leonid нет именно толщины, я добавил это в вопрос. Основная проблема в этом. Вы правы, круг не может быть трехмерным, я просто имел в виду шайбу

Comment: Думаю, такое только в Three.js тогда. Или еще пару промежуточных шагов добавить и менять кадры да и все. GIF сделать. Если саму толщину и добавить с помощью десятка разнесенных на разную глубину круглых элементов, то сам рисунок гурта вряд ли получится нанести...

Comment: Можно гурт сделать отдельным анимированным блоком. Но работа по подготовке графики, расчеты, это за гранью бесплатной помощи.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov это неоправданные усилия ради тривиальной задачи

Answer (score 5):

**Решение с помощью canvas:**

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('coin');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const w = canvas.width = 600;
const h = canvas.height = 180;

const coinWidth = 8;
const radius = Math.min(w,h)/3;
const risk = 0.8;

let pattern;
let heads;
let tails;
let gurt;

let pos1 = 0;
let pos2 = coinWidth;

let scale = 1;
let direction = 0.01;

let image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/02/15/57/69/500_F_215576902_nDCSvmb5QL3D6kHknzy9gorsFoBEFV8t.jpg';
image.onload = () => {
    let faceCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    let fw = faceCanvas.width = radius*2 + 2;
    let fh = faceCanvas.height = radius*2 + 2;
    let context = faceCanvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(image,28,13,210,210,0,0,fw,fh);
    tails = ctx.createPattern(faceCanvas, 'no-repeat');
    
    context.drawImage(image,262,13,210,210,0,0,fw,fh);
    heads = ctx.createPattern(faceCanvas, 'no-repeat');
    pattern = heads;
    
    context.fillStyle = '#efd894';
    context.fillRect(0,0,fw,fh);
    for(let i=0; i < fh; i+=risk*2){
        context.fillStyle = '#efd894';
        context.fillRect(0,i,fw,risk);
        context.fillStyle = '#7b521c';
        context.fillRect(0,i+risk,fw,risk);
    }
    gurt = ctx.createPattern(faceCanvas,'no-repeat');
    
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#7b521c';
    ctx.strokeWidth = 1;
    
    ctx.translate(w/2,h/2);
    draw();
}

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(-w/2,-h/2,w,h);
    
    if(scale >= 1){
        direction = -direction;
        [pos1,pos2] = [pos2,pos1];
    } else if(scale <= 0){
        direction = - direction;
        pattern = pattern== tails ? heads : tails;
        [pos1,pos2] = [pos2,pos1];
    }
    
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(pos1-(Math.abs(scale)*pos1),0);
    ctx.scale(scale,1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.translate(-radius,-radius-1);
    ctx.fillStyle = gurt;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, -radius-1, coinWidth*(1-scale), radius*2+2);
    ctx.translate(-radius,-radius-1);
    ctx.fillStyle = gurt;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(pos2-(Math.abs(scale)*pos2),0);
    ctx.scale(scale,1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.translate(-radius,-radius);
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
        
    ctx.restore();
    
    scale += direction;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="coin"></canvas>
```

Comment: Обновил решение с участием изображения и отрисовки рисок на гурте. Теперь хоть понятно зачем canvas))

Comment: вчитываюсь в ваш код (плюсую, разумеется), очень красиво получилось, а вы полагали надежды лишь на three.js, спасибо за старания )

Answer (score 2):

Отличное решение от [h](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416688/%E1%85%A0h%E1%85%A0) на чистом CSS:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
  background-color: white;
}

.coin {
  position: relative;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: rotate 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(1turn);
  }
}
.coin__layer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(black, black 1vmin, white 1vmin, white 1.5vmin);
}

.coin__layer:first-child,
.coin__layer:last-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3vmin;
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.1vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.15vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.2vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.25vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.3vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.35vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(8) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.4vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(9) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.45vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(10) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.5vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(11) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.55vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(12) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.6vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(13) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.65vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(14) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.7vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(15) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.75vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(16) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.8vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(17) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.85vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(18) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.9vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(19) {
  transform: translateZ(-0.95vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(20) {
  transform: translateZ(-1vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(21) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.05vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(22) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.1vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(23) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.15vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(24) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.2vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(25) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.25vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(26) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.3vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(27) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.35vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(28) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.4vmin);
}

.coin__layer:nth-child(29) {
  transform: translateZ(-1.45vmin);
}

.coin__layer:last-child {
  transform: translateZ(-1.5vmin) rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<body translate="no">
  <div class="coin">
  <div class="coin__layer">FRONT</div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer"></div>
  <div class="coin__layer">BACK</div>
</div>
</body>
```